# Change interval in cache to update GPS - Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to obtain GPS position in BackgroundWorker. I read, that data are obtained from cache and these cache is update every 15minutes. Is it possible to re-schedule update interval for cache?
Now I'm using emulator, and I always get NoData in event StatusChanged.

Ok could you explain me, how it works in emulator, please?
Here is my code:

```
private GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);

    private void StartGeoWatcher()
    {
        watcher.StatusChanged += GeoWatcherStatusChanged;
        watcher.PositionChanged += GeoWatcherPositionChanged;
        watcher.Start();
    }

    void GeoWatcherPositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {

    }

    void GeoWatcherStatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
                case GeoPositionStatus.Initializing:
                    break;
                case GeoPositionStatus.Ready:
                    break;
                case GeoPositionStatus.NoData:
                    break;
                case GeoPositionStatus.Disabled:
                    break;
        }

    }
```

I start emulator in my app. After that, I select some position in Additional tools. When position is selected, click on button in app and the periodictask is going to run. 
First: StatusChanged is called with status "Initializing". Second: StatusChanged is called with status "NoData". I don't know why, because I've selected location in additional tools.

Comment: The answer is - no, it's not.

Comment: So I think, I've found solution. First I have to create GeoCoordinateWatcher in mainapplication and call Start(). It gets position. After that, I can use GeoCoordinateWatcher in BackgroundAgent, without to get NoData.

Comment: Wait, you forgot to call Start() on your watcher?

Comment: Did you see my code above? I call Start() in method OnInvoke(). After that, StatusChanged_Event is called twice: First with Status.Initializing, second with Status.NoData. So I've tried to call Start() in MainApp firstly and then in BackgroundAgent. I thought, calling Start() in BackgroundAgent it's enough, but it isn't

Answer (score 0):

This isn't true, you can get realtime GPS positions with specifying GeoPositionAccuracy.High for [GeoCoordinateWatcher.DesiredAccuracy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.desiredaccuracy.aspx) property. But this will drain your battery.

Even on normal settings you should be able to get almost real time position.

Comment: What is the difference between BW and UI thread for accessing GPS data?

Comment: Yes, but from BackgroundWorker I can't